# "Everything" for fat32 filesystems?

Tags: windows, file-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the fastest desktop search tools you’ve used on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8654/whats-the-fastest-desktop-search-tools-youve-used-on-windows)

Can someone suggest me a quick file search utility for xp like "everything" from [voidtools.com](http://www.voidtools.com/). I have my drives formatted in Fat32. *Everything* doesn't support fat32 it seems. Thanx.

Comment: There are a few questions that go in the similar direction already: http://superuser.com/questions/100502/please-suggest-a-file-search-tool-for-windows-that-is-not-google-desktop-and-doe – http://superuser.com/questions/8654/whats-the-fastest-desktop-search-tools-youve-used-on-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Locate32](http://www.locate32.net/) might be a replacement.

Comment: Locate32 is fast enough and great.. except it has no customizable GUI.. I only needed the search bar and the results.. I could not disable the filter options.. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

How about [**Google Desktop**](http://desktop.google.com/) Search?

Comment: Its good.. I only wanted local file search.. It also takes some amount of cpu.. It has more than what I need.. Thanx